# After Rebooting RHEL Server, chef-server can't start

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, chef-infra, chef-recipe

"usr/sbin/setup-chef-server.sh "

Error while chef-server start up

Checking RabbitMQ...

Starting CouchDB...

Starting couchdb: already running[WARNING]
Enabling Chef Services...

Starting Chef Services...

Starting chef-server: [FAILED]

Starting chef-server-webui: [FAILED]

Starting chef-solr: /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find chef-solr (>= 0) amongst [bunny-0.7.9, chef-10.16.2, erubis-2.7.0, highline-1.6.15, ipaddress-0.8.0, json-1.6.1, mime-types-1.19, mixlib-authentication-1.3.0, mixlib-cli-1.2.2, mixlib-config-1.1.2, mixlib-log-1.4.1, mixlib-shellout-1.1.0, moneta-0.6.0, net-ssh-2.2.2, net-ssh-gateway-1.1.0, net-ssh-multi-1.1, ohai-6.14.0, polyglot-0.3.3, rest-client-1.6.7, systemu-2.5.2, treetop-1.4.12, uuidtools-2.1.3, yajl-ruby-1.1.0] (Gem::LoadError)`

```
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in 'to_spec'
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1210:in 'gem'
from /usr/bin/chef-solr:18
```

[FAILED]

Starting chef-expander: /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find chef-expander (>= 0) amongst [bunny-0.7.9, chef-10.16.2, erubis-2.7.0, highline-1.6.15, ipaddress-0.8.0, json-1.6.1, mime-types-1.19, mixlib-authentication-1.3.0, mixlib-cli-1.2.2, mixlib-config-1.1.2, mixlib-log-1.4.1, mixlib-shellout-1.1.0, moneta-0.6.0, net-ssh-2.2.2, net-ssh-gateway-1.1.0, net-ssh-multi-1.1, ohai-6.14.0, polyglot-0.3.3, rest-client-1.6.7, systemu-2.5.2, treetop-1.4.12, uuidtools-2.1.3, yajl-ruby-1.1.0] (Gem::LoadError)

```
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/chef-expander:18
```

[FAILED]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My chef gem version on the server also has 0.10.6 which seems to then install chef-expander, chef-solr, chef-server, chef-server-webui and others. Is chef-10 not just the client? – PatrickWalker 2 mins ago edit

http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Installing+Chef+Server+Manually seems to indicate that yeah 0.10.x is the server gem and looking at the release notes 10.X appears to be client